# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined' in backend.min.js:2

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typescript, visual-composer

I have a problem with Visual Composer, I have build a website, now I want to change the images of the homepage, but when I click the edit button to edit the image, I can select the image from the media gallery, but I can not save the image in Visual Composer to display it on my website.

My console throws this when I click  the edit button of a image:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined backend.min.js:2
```

The code at backend.min.js:2, unminified:

```
initDependency: function () {
        var callDependencies = {};
        _.each(this.mapped_params, function (param) {
            if (_.isObject(param) && _.isObject(param.dependency)) {
                var rules = param.dependency;
                if (_.isString(param.dependency.element)) {
                    var $masters, $slave;
                    $masters = $("[name=" + param.dependency.element + "].wpb_vc_param_value", this.$content), $slave = $("[name= " + param.param_name + "].wpb_vc_param_value", this.$content), _.each($masters, function (master) {
                        var $master, name;
                        $master = $(master), name = $master.attr("name"), _.isArray(this.dependent_elements[$master.attr("name")]) || (this.dependent_elements[$master.attr("name")] = []), this.dependent_elements[$master.attr("name")].push($slave), !$master.data("dependentSet") && $master.attr("data-dependent-set", "true") && $master.bind("keyup change", this.hookDependent), callDependencies[name] || (callDependencies[name] = $master)
                    }, this)
                }
                _.isString(rules.callback) && window[rules.callback].call(this)
            }
        }, this), this.doCheckTabs = !1, _.each(callDependencies, function (obj) {
            this.hookDependent({currentTarget: obj})
        }, this), this.doCheckTabs = !0, this.checkTabs(), callDependencies = null
    },
```

After researching the window variable, I know that the window[rules.callback] is undefined, it does not exist. The rules index is not visible in 'console.log(window)'.

I am using WordPress 4.6.1 and Visual Composer 4.12.1 with the WooPress theme, it worked very well.

Who can help me, please?

Comment: What populates window[rules.callback] in the first place? 
There should be a script that creates properties on the window for this function to then find the properties.

Comment: I know that there have to be a script that defines window[rules.callback], so the issue is solved. I am searching for anyone which is having the same issue and having the fix.

Answer (score 0):

From backend.min.js I remove this part of code:

```
_.isString(rules.callback)&&window[rules.callback].call(this)
```

You may search this part of the code and delete it.
It's the only workaround.